# SharePoint - How to identify whether a user has granted direct permissions or through a group?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, wss

I want to find whether a user in a site has been granted permissions directly or he is inheriting permissions from a group. How can I do that using SharePoint object model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is a direct way to do this. One option is to get all the groups he is in and then see if this group belongs to a another group. If so then he is inheriting the permission from the group. Not a good solution though. :-)